# Angular + TypeScript: $watchCollection, "controller as" good practice

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope

In general in my Angular / TypeScript apps I've tended to use the "controller as" syntax.

However, for a CRUD screen I'm currently working on I've found myself diverting away from this.  So that I can take advantage of `$watchCollection`  / checking for changes etc I've found myself using the pattern advised by that excellent chap @basarat [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E).  Namely, in the video (which pre-dates "controller as" syntax in Angular) @basarat creates a variable representing the controller on the `$scope` called `vm`.  And in the same way as with using a "controller as vm" in the view you can still use the `vm.myProperty` /  `vm.myFunction()`style syntax to interact with your model.

So, the controller looks like this:

```
module controllers {

    "use strict";

    interface sageEditRouteParams extends ng.route.IRouteParamsService {
        id: number;
    }

    interface sageEditScope extends ng.IScope {
        vm: SageEdit;
    }

    class SageEdit {

        log: loggerFunction;
        sage: sage;
        title: string;

        private _hasChanges: boolean;

        static $inject = ["$routeParams", "$scope", "common", "datacontext"];
        constructor(
            private $routeParams: sageEditRouteParams,
            private $scope: sageEditScope,
            private common: common,
            private datacontext: datacontext
            ) {

            this.sage = undefined;
            this.title = "Sage Edit";

            this.log = common.logger.getLogFn(controllerId);

            $scope.vm = this;
            $scope.$watchCollection("vm.sage", (newSage: sage, oldSage: sage) => {
                if (newSage && oldSage) {
                    this._hasChanges = true;
                }
            });

            this.activate();
        }

        // Prototype methods

        activate() {
            var id = this.$routeParams.id;
            var dataPromises: ng.IPromise<any>[] = [this.getSage(id)];

            this.common.activateController(dataPromises, controllerId)
                .then(() => {
                    this.log("Activated Sage Edit View");
                    this.title = "Sage Edit: " + this.sage.name;
                });
        }

        getSage(id: number) {
            return this.datacontext.sage.getById(id).then(data => {
                this.sage = data;
                this._hasChanges = false;
            });
        }

        get hasChanges(): boolean {
            return this._hasChanges;
        }
    }

    var controllerId = "sageEdit";
    angular.module("app").controller(controllerId, SageEdit);
}
```

And the view like this:

```
<section class="mainbar" ng-controller="sageEdit">
    <section class="matter">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-info"
                        ng-click="vm.cancel()"
                        ng-disabled="!vm.canSave">
                    <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>Cancel
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-info"
                        ng-click="vm.save()"
                        ng-disabled="!vm.canSave">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>Save
                </button>
                <span ng-show="vm.hasChanges"
                      class="dissolve-animation ng-hide">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk text-info"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="widget wgreen">
                <div data-cc-widget-header title="{{vm.title}}"></div>
                <div class="widget-content form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">Name</label>
                        <input class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" ng-model="vm.sage.name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">Username</label>
                        <input class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" ng-model="vm.sage.userName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">Email</label>
                        <input class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" 
                               type="email"
                               ng-model="vm.sage.email" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

What I'm putting together seems to work just fine but I wanted to put it out there and get some other views.  Are there:

1. any shortcomings with this approach
2. any reasons this is a bad idea
3. better alternatives?

I've done a little digging but found not anything conclusive.

Comment: Also updated answer to respond for `controller as` thanks for the mentions ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Magic string removal

For

```
$scope.$watchCollection("vm.sage", (newSage: sage, oldSage: sage) => {
```

You can also do for refactoring ease:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(()=>this.sage, (newSage: sage, oldSage: sage) => {
```

In certain scenarios when you try to watch something like `foo.bar` where `foo` is still undefined you can use a safe wrapper function `safeWatch(()=>this.foo.bar)`:

```
 function safeWatch<T extends Function>(expression: T) {
        return () => {
            try {
                return expression();
            }
            catch (e) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

## Controller as vs. $scope.vm

Fron source code:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/36831eccd1da37c089f2141a2c073a6db69f3e1d/src/ng/controller.js#L95

That is exactly what angular is doing for you. i.e. `$scope.vm = instance` (where `vm == indentifier`) So they are equivalent

Comment: Thanks @basarat - works a treat! (The OCD programmer inside me shrieking "**must** have consistent code" is satisfied)

Comment: the only issue is when when you watch something like `this.foo.bar` when `foo` is not yet defined. We have a `Safe evaluate` function for that. Let me post that as well.